# How to handle Vue component content before data has finished loading

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I'm loading some product category data from Prismic into my Nuxt project, and I'm looking for some clarification regarding best practices. Specifically, how to handle the state in which the data is still being fetched, and there's no content to display in the sidebar.

Right now, here's what I've got working:

I have a sidebar component (`Sidebar.vue`):

```html
<template>
    <div class="xl:flex-shrink-0 xl:w-64 border-r border-gray-200 pt-5 pb-4 bg-white overflow-y-auto ">
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold text-gray-800">{{ navigation.heading }}</h3>
        <div class="mt-5 flex-grow flex flex-col">
            <nav class="flex-1 px-2 space-y-1 bg-white" aria-label="Sidebar">
            <div v-for="(category, index) in navigation.categories" :key="index">
                <SidebarItem v-if="!category.subcategories.length" :category="category"/>

                <SidebarSection v-else-if="category.subcategories.length" @click="toggleExpansion(index)" :category="category"/>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            navigation: new Navigation('Categories')
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        const that = this
        this.fetchCategories()
            .then(function() {
                that.navigation = that.$store.getters.navigation
            })
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions({ fetchCategories: 'fetchCategories' })
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I have a `navigation` property which will contain all of the data required to populate the sidebar. At the moment, I have initialised a placeholder instance (`new Navigation('Categories')`), as without this, Vue reports that `navigation` is undefined.

This doesn't feel like an ideal way to go about this. What would be the most appropriate way to handle this intermediary state before the data is loaded, without providing a placeholder instance?

Comment: I don't really see much wrong with what you're doing. You're giving the `navigation` property a type which will help you when debugging, etc., now just make sure you are doing your `null` checks before you use it and move on IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt's [`fetch` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook) could be useful here. It exposes `$fetchState` (includes `pending`, `error`, and `timestamp`) to use imperatively or in your template. Your template could check the `pending` flag before rendering the `navigation` data:

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="!$fetchState.pending" 
        class="xl:flex-shrink-0 xl:w-64 border-r border-gray-200 pt-5 pb-4 bg-white overflow-y-auto">
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold text-gray-800">{{ navigation.heading }}</h3>
        <div class="mt-5 flex-grow flex flex-col">
            <nav class="flex-1 px-2 space-y-1 bg-white" aria-label="Sidebar">
            <div v-for="(category, index) in navigation.categories" :key="index">
                <SidebarItem v-if="!category.subcategories.length" :category="category"/>
                <SidebarSection v-else-if="category.subcategories.length" @click="toggleExpansion(index)" :category="category"/>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
    // BEFORE:
    // async mounted() {
    //     const that = this
    //     this.fetchCategories()
    //     .then(function() {
    //         that.navigation = that.$store.getters.navigation
    //     })
    // },

    // AFTER:
    async fetch() {
        await this.fetchCategories()
        this.navigation = this.$store.getters.navigation
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew something didn't feel quite right about my current implementation. Page loads much more seamlessly now and code is cleaner. Thanks!